# Configuring Apache Spark Logging with Scala and logback

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j2, logback

I am very confused with setting up logging with Apache Spark. Apache spark used Log4j for logging and it generates huge amount of log data. 
Is there a way to setup log4j for spark logs and use logback for application log. I am quite conversant with logback but **it seems** spark only support log4j.
Below piece of code was working fine till i introduced apache spark. Any help in this regard will be helpful.

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging

import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.xml.{Elem, XML}



object MainApp extends App with LazyLogging  {



  val currency = new YahooCurrencyLoader() with CurrencyParameters
  val ccy = currency.getXML(currency.ccyUrl) match {

    case Success(v) => XML.save("PreviousRun.xml",v); logger.info("XML has been saved for use")
    case Failure(ex) => logger.error("XML extraction failed. Look at Yahoo extraction class. ${ex.getMessage}" )

  }

  val xmllocation: String = "./PreviousRun.xml"
  val loadxml: Elem = XML.loadFile(xmllocation)
  //print(loadxml)
  //print(currency.findCurrency(loadxml,"GBP"))

  logger.info("USD CAD Cross is " + currency.findCurrency(loadxml,"CAD").head)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop messages displaying on spark console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-messages-displaying-on-spark-console)

Answer (score 25):

I do not know if you use `sbt` or `maven` but that is where it should all start. Myself I use `sbt` so I will give you an example how we have solved this problem.

1. Apache Spark uses log4j 1.2.xx

---

That is true and it is really problematic if you do not want to use the same logging implementation. But there is help!

First, exclude the following libs from `spark` dependencies:

- `log4j`
- `slf4j-log4j12`

For `sbt` (using `sbt-assembly`) it looks like this:

```
lazy val spark16 = Seq("spark-core", "spark-sql", "spark-hive")
  .map("org.apache.spark" %% _ % "1.6.1")
  .map(_.excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(name = "log4j"),
    ExclusionRule(name = "slf4j-log4j12")
  ))
```

2. Redirect log4j logging to slf4j

---

A detailed description can be found here: https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html
And the module that is in our interest is: `log4j-over-slf4j`

> The `log4j-over-slf4j` module contains replacements of most widely used log4j classes, namely org.apache.log4j.Category, org.apache.log4j.Logger, org.apache.log4j.Priority, org.apache.log4j.Level, org.apache.log4j.MDC, and org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator. **These replacement classes redirect all work to their corresponding SLF4J classes.**

So we can have all the logs redirected back to `slf4j` from where some other logging implementation could pick it up.

Easy, simply add this dependency to your application

```
"org.slf4j" % "log4j-over-slf4j" % "1.7.25"
```

3. Add desired logging implementation

---

In our case it was (like yours) `logback`, so we added it as dependency:

```
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
```

Add some `logback.xml` configuration to your classpath, for example in `src/main/resources` and enjoy!

### spark-submit

If you need help using `Logback` while deploying your app with `spark-submit` please follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480145/1549135

Answer (score 4):

I have used the following imports:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

Sample code as shown below.

```
Object SparkCode {

val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

  logger.info("Connection Started . ")

  // Create Spark Context and go on..

  }

}
```

And you are sorted.