# Configuring Apache Spark Logging with Maven and logback and finally throwing message to Loggly

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, logback, loggly

I'm having trouble getting my Spark Application to ignore Log4j, in order to use Logback.  One of the reasons i'm trying to use logback, is for the loggly appender it supports.

I have the following dependencies and exclusions in my pom file.  (versions are in my dependency manager in main pom library.)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>            
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>           
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.logback-extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-ext-loggly</artifactId>         
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>           
    </dependency>
```

I have referenced these two articles:

[Separating application logs in Logback from Spark Logs in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126107/separating-application-logs-in-logback-from-spark-logs-in-log4j/45480145#45480145)
[Configuring Apache Spark Logging with Scala and logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356887/configuring-apache-spark-logging-with-scala-and-logback)

I've tried using first using (when running spark-submit) :
--conf "spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true" 
--conf "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true"

but receive the error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.ge
tLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/spark/util/ChildFirstURLClassLoader) of the current cl
ass, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4
j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
```

I would like to get it working with the above, but then i also looked at trying the below
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=$libs" 
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=$libs"

but since i'm passing my uber jar to spark submit locally AND (on a Amazon EMR cluster) i really can't be specifying a library file location that will be local to my machine.  Since the uber jar contains the files, is there a way for it to use those files? Am i forced to copy these libraries to the master/nodes on the EMR cluster when the spark app finally runs from there?

The first approach about using the userClassPathFirst seems like the best route though.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved the issue and had several problems going on.

So in order to get Spark to allow logback to work, the solution that worked for me was from a combination of items from the articles i posted above, and in addition a cert file problem.

The cert file i was using to pass into spark-submit was incomplete and overriding the base truststore certs. This was causing a problem SENDING Https messages to Loggly.

Part 1 change:
Update maven to shade org.slf4j (as stated in an answer by @matemaciek)

```
      </dependencies>
         ...
         <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>                
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.logback-extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-ext-loggly</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Main-Class>com.TestClass</Main-Class>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.slf4j</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.shaded.slf4j</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Part 1a: the logback.xml

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="logglyAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.ext.loggly.LogglyAppender">
        <endpointUrl>https://logs-01.loggly.com/bulk/TOKEN/tag/TAGS/</endpointUrl>
        <pattern>${hostName} %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT} %p %t %c %M - %m%n</pattern>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
          <pattern>${hostName} %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT} %p %t %c %M - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="logglyAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Part 2 change: The MainClass

```
import org.slf4j.*;

public class TestClass {

    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestClass.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        log.info("this is a test message");
    }
}
```

Part 3 change:
i was submitting spark application as such (example):

```
sparkspark-submit --deploy-mode client --class com.TestClass --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:/src/testproject/rds-truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:/src/testproject/rds-truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit" com/target/testproject-0.0.1.jar
```

So the above spark-submit failed on a HTTPS certification problem (that was when Loggly was being contacted to send the message to loggly service) because the rds-truststore.jks overwrote the certs without all certs. I changed this to use cacerts store, and it now had all the certs it needed.

No more error at the Loggly part when sending this

```
sparkspark-submit --deploy-mode client --class com.TestClass --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:/src/testproject/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:/src/testproject/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit" com/target/testproject-0.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to usein spark opts -Dspark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlogback.configurationFile=/spark/logback/logback.xml

In logback.xml you should have settings for logback.